# Regular expression in javascript how to find content between two "special" characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following line of text, I need to look for the content inside `$$` and extract values for `id=` and `description=`.

Could you point me out in the right direction, I tried few times with no success (actually I tried this one `^\$\$(.*?)\$\$`)

```
$$id=uniq_id&description=some_description$$ Any text after
// result should be: ['uniq_id', 'some_description', 'Any text after']

$$id=uniq_id$$ Any text after
// result should be: ['uniq_id', '', 'Any text after']

Any text after
// result should be: ['','','Any text after']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use 1 capturing group `(.*?)` to capture between `$$` and `$$`.

If the `id` should be there and the description is optional, you could use 3 capturing groups where the part that matches description is optional`:

```
^\$\$id=(\w+)(?:&description=(\w+))?\$\$(.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/naCQes/1/)

```js
const regex = /^\$\$id=(\w+)(?:&description=(\w+))?\$\$(.*)/;
const strings = [
  "$$id=uniq_id&description=some_description$$ Any text after",
  "$$id=uniq_id$$ Any text after"
];

strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s.match(regex));
});
```

Comment: sorry, I made an edit to my question... I need also what is on the right side on the last $$

Comment: @Radex On the same line like `^\$\$id=(\w+)&description=(\w+)\$\$(.*)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/biNxhu/1)

Comment: look here, I have also a case I need to return only if there is a single id:

https://regex101.com/r/JbbFLC/3

Comment: for example if &description=some_description is not provided

Comment: for example I am using /^\$\$(?:id=(\w+))?(?:&description=(\w+))?(.*)/ now nut I need to remove the $$ from the last group

Comment: Like https://regex101.com/r/naCQes/1 Should only description be optional?

Comment: @Radex I have updated my answer with the last example.

Comment: I have another tweak, I made a new question.. could you please have a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53660967/regext-how-to-math-html-tag-in-a-string

Answer (score 2):

A pattern such as

```
\$\$(?:id=(\w+))?(?:&description=(\w+))?
```

should work for this.

Comment: I made an edit to my question... I need also what is on the right side on the last $$

Comment: sorry, I made an edit to my question... I need also what is on the right side on the last $$